# Unity Oculus - Rotating empty parent on character rotates on a weird axis when player isn't standing at origin

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Sorry I know the title is really confusing.

Basically the camera and hands are nested under an empty object. This empty object is then used to rotate the character and teleport the character. Thing is, the camera is able to freely move around and away the empty object. Making rotation seem like you're running in a circle instead of just rotating. Then when you teleport it's a little offset. Like if you shoot the teleport beam straight down you move because it's teleporting the empty object to the camera which moves the camera.

So if the headset and camera aren't exactly on top of the empty object everything gets wonky. I understand the problem just can't figure out a solution.

I tried resetting the position on every teleport but you can still move away and spin in circles. As well as resetting resets the orientation and that's not exactly what I need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to approach this. A crude, and not very elegant solution would be to parent your camera parent to yet another object, created in runtime, that would assume the position of the actual player camera when the rotation starts. You can reparent objects dynamically, so you could rotate this newly spawned object, which would give you the desired effect, and then loose the top parent when the rotation stops.

Alternatively you could move your camera parent as you rotate it, based on transforming the position relative to the player camera position. A bit more elegant but there's probably a few lines of math that you would have to write